# Convert MS Word (.doc and .docx) file to HTML using Python on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, libreoffice, openoffice.org

Try to convert MS Word files to HTML using Python on AWS Lambda. For .docx, I know there is a library called python-docx. But when it comes to .doc, I still cannot find an elegant and simple solution because most of possible solutions are using LibreOffice or OpenOffice.

Is there a way to make a portable version of LibreOffice/OpenOffice that can be manipulated by Python scripts on AWS Lambda? Or, is there a Python library for .doc file that I omit?

Comment: Did you find any solution? if so please share your experience. I also want to use some features of LibreOffice/OpenOffice in Lambda. Basically I want to convert .doc file into .pdf.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for LibreOffice running in AWS Lambda, this might help you. Recently I managed to create a portable version which runs in Lambda.

https://github.com/vladgolubev/serverless-libreoffice

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems no elegant solutions to tackle this problem at this moment. I had tried to make a portable version of LibreOffice/OpenOffice, but the biggest problem is the size, which exceeds the AWS Lambda's limit.

Maybe you want to give **Pandoc** a try although it cannot process .doc file. But I successfully use it on AWS Lambda. You can visit [here](https://zeckli.github.io/en/2017/08/04/build-pandoc-and-run-it-on-aws-lambda-en.html) to know how to make a portable version for AWS Lambda.